# MongoDB Java Inserting Throws Can't find a codec for class org.variabel.BsonDocument

Tags: java, json, mongodb

I'm learning MongoDB with Java. I'm trying to insert data to MongoDB with Java driver. i used Document for org.jsoup.nodes.Document. So i create class BsonDocument that extends org.bson.Document.
But i got error :

> Can't find a codec for class org.variabel.BsonDocument

here is the class org.variabel.BsonDocument :

```
import java.util.Map;
import org.bson.Document;
public class BsonDocument extends Document{
    public BsonDocument() {
        super();
    }

    public BsonDocument(Map<String, Object> map) {
        super(map);
    }

    public BsonDocument(String key, Object value){
        super(key, value);
    }
}
```

implemented in another class :

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient( "localhost" , 27017 );
// Now connect to your databases
MongoDatabase db = mongoClient.getDatabase("tes123");

BsonDocument document = new BsonDocument();

document.put("name", "Sony");
document.put("age", 30);
document.put("createdDate", new Date());
db.getCollection("tes123").insertOne(document);
```

Comment: Why did you create a new class BsonDocument ? Can you tell us what you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: there are two data types Document from org.bspn.Document and org.jsoup.nodes.Document.
i just avoided a conflict between them.

Comment: i mean org.bson.Document

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code,with only change one line,and it goes right.
here is my version

```
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;

import java.util.Date;

/**
 * @author Hanz
 * @date 2019/8/22
 */
public class testDocument {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("127.0.0.1",27017);   // i changed this 'localhost' to '127.0.0.1'
        MongoDatabase db = mongoClient.getDatabase("test");

        BsonDocument document = new BsonDocument();
        document.put("name", "Sony");
        document.put("age", 30);
        document.put("createdDate", new Date());
        db.getCollection("tes123").insertOne(document);
    }

}
```

the other file is same as yours,but in case,here is my code

```
import org.bson.Document;
import java.util.Map;
/**
 * @author Hanz
 * @date 2019/8/22
 */
public class BsonDocument extends Document {

    public BsonDocument() {
        super();
    }

    public BsonDocument(Map<String, Object> map) {
        super(map);
    }

    public BsonDocument(String key, Object value){
        super(key, value);
    }
}
```

have you checked your mongo database see if it has the db "test123" ?
hope you solved this problem or this answer can help you:)